# submit my form through ajax using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

Just wanted to ask, how will i submit my form through ajax using javascript.
Here's my code:

```
<script>
 function show_edit(bugid,device)
 {
   document.getElementById('updateform').style.visibility='visible';
   document.getElementById('U_bugid').value=bugid;
   document.getElementById('U_device').value=device;
 }
 function hide()
 {
   document.getElementById('updateform').style.visibility='hidden';
 }
</script>
```

Here's my hidden form

```
   <div id"update_form" >
  <form onsubmit="ajax_submit();">
  <fieldset>
  <label for="maskset">MASKSET</label><input type='text' name='bugid' id='U_bugid' readonly >
 <label for="device">DEVICE</label><input type='text' name='device' id='U_device'   readonly>

 <label for="reason">Comments</label><textarea rows=10 cols=40 name='reason'></textarea>
 <input id="S_update" class='S_update' value="Update Data" type="submit" >
</form>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Can i put it this way below, when i click submit it will immediately submit through ajax code together with my new comment(from textarea):

```
  function show_edit(bugid,device)
  {
  var maskset;
  document.getElementById('updateform').style.visibility='visible';
  document.getElementById('U_bugid').value=bugid;
    document.getElementById('U_device').value=device;

   function ajax_submit()     
   {  //code in submitting ajax i already know; }
   }
```

Will this work?

Comment: have you tried it? what happened?

Comment: Most probably this will not work... is the `ajax_submit` inside the `show_edit` function? The onsubmit will not work then...

Comment: i didnt work :( if i separate funtion ajax_submit() most probably i can't get/access my data (bugid,device from show_edit funtion)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It seems that what you want to do is to stop the submition of your code you need to  add `onsubmit="return  ajax_submit()"` to your HTML and make sure the function return `false`.

```
function ajax_submit()     
   {  
return false;
   }
```

By the looks of your code you would greatly benefit from getting  with [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) in order to select DOM elements as it will simplify your life greatly.

On that note it would make your life a hell of a lot easier using jQuery Ajax. Specially if you [read up on jQuery AJAX functions](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) .

```
$.post("test.php", { bugid: $('#U_bugid').val(), device: $('#U_device').val() } );
```

Comment: i saw there's a jqueryui modal form... I haven't tried it yet, i just want to be familiar with javascript first without using library, but if i cannot really find any solution, then i jump jquery :).

Comment: I would recommend you using jQuery as if you are a web-developer is the mainstream library that you would use and will save you lots of headaches with browser compatibility